# SwiftUI - Variable updating from TextField input

Tags: class, swiftui, struct, binding, textfield

I have a variable that I want to update and use in multiple places. It's actually the tilt angle of a solar panel. So I declare this as a class rather than a struct e.g:

```
class Variables: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tiltAngle: Double = 25.0 
}
```

It is given a default value of 25. From this an image will be generated based on the tilt angle:

[image]

But I want the user to be able to alter the tilt angle, from a TextField:

```
HStack {
     Text("Tilt Angle")
          .padding(.leading, 16)
     TextField("Tilt Angle", value: $variables.tiltAngle, formatter: formatter)
          .disableAutocorrection(true)
     Text("°")
          .padding(.trailing, 16)
```

}

What is happening is that in some place the variable, variables.tiltAngle, appears to be updated and not in others.

So the orange number in the gray/grey row updates correctly:

```
struct PanelSpacingView: View {
    @StateObject var variables = Variables()
    var body: some View {
    
           let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
               let formatter = NumberFormatter()
               formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
               return formatter
           }()
      
           ...

            // Grey Banner
            ZStack {
               Rectangle().fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame(width: GlobalVariables.screenWidth, height: 24)
                HStack {
                    Text(variables.tiltAngle, format: .number)
```

But if I alter the TextField number the variable doesn't get passed to the section that redraws the grey lines? The print output shows it still to be 25 even when I have altered it in the TextField.

```
struct DrawPanels: Shape {
    @ObservedObject var variables = Variables()
    let radians = 3.14159/180
  
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        variables.endX = Int(variables.panelWidth * cos(variables.tiltAngle * radians))
        variables.endY = Int(variables.panelWidth * sin(variables.tiltAngle * radians))
       
        let _ = print("Executed", variables.tiltAngle)
        let baselineY = rect.maxY - 0
        let baselineXOffset: Int = 10
        let panelY = Int(rect.maxY) - variables.endY
        let panel1X = baselineXOffset + variables.endX
        let panel2X = baselineXOffset + Int(rect.midX) + variables.endX
    
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + 10, y: baselineY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: panel1X, y: panelY))
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + 10, y: baselineY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: panel2X, y: panelY))
        return path
    }
  //  let _ = print("Executed")
}
```

Is this the right approach? What do you advise?

Comment: In `DrawPanels` you should have `@ObservedObject var variables: Variables`, and pass the ObservedObject into it, from up the view hierarchy.

Comment: As answered from workingdog above. In DrawPanels you are initialising a different variables Object and so it has different value. You need to not set it in DrawPanels and pass it in from the PanelSpacingView to use the same @StateObject you are updating in that view.

Comment: Understood - will report back - many thanks.

Comment: But how then in a struct can I pull the true variable? I thought that that's what the ObserverVariable allows me to do.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for explaining the cause(s). The correct syntax that unifies the variables would appear to be...

The initial class:

```
class Variables: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tiltAngle: Double = 25.0 
}
```

At the start:

```
struct PanelSpacingView: View {
    @ObservedObject var variables: Variables = Variables()
```

And when you want to receive the variables in a struct:

```
struct DrawPanels: Shape {
    @ObservedObject var variables: Variables
```